If eigenvalues of two matrices are equal then the matrices are equal?
Suppose $k_i$ and $f_i$ are eigenvalues of two density matrices A and B,
If $k_i=f_i$ then A=B?
If the answer is no, under which conditions the statement holds?

By a density matrix, I will assume you mean a Hermitian matrix with unit trace. Such a matrix has the property that all eigenvalues are real, and there is guaranteed to be a spectral decomposition:
$$M = O D O^{-1}$$
Therefore given a set of real eigenvalues encoded in diagonal $D$, we can construct a large class of unequal matrices $M$ by choosing different eigenvectors, as encoded in $O$.
The only exception would be the case where all eigenvalues are equal to ${\bf1}/N$, $N$ being the size of the matrix. This is the only density matrix which is a multiple of the identity. As a result, no matter what eigenvectors $O$ I choose, there is a unique matrix $M={\bf1} / N$.

What if for both matrices A and B, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are equal? Then can we say A=B?

@reza No, see the example of Frederik in the other answer. You additionally need that the eigenvalues are associated to the same eigenvectors

A simple counterexample are the matrices
$$
\rho=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}\qquad\omega=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which have the same eigenvalues ($0,1$) but are obviously not the same. In general same eigenvalues only tell you that the two matrices are equivalent up to same unitary transformation, that is, $\rho=U\omega U^\dagger$ for some unitary matrix $U$.
